# Which universe is Commander Landry from?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, star-trek-discovery

In three early episodes of *Star Trek Discovery*'s first season (*Context is for Kings, The Butcher's Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry, and What's Past is Prologue)*, viewers are briefly introduced to Lorca's right hand woman, [Commander Landry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFbyo.jpg), being Chief of Security of the USS Discovery vessel.

[image: Sharma is a cylon again]

But given the ruthless nature of the character, and the revelation about

> Lorca being form the Mirror Universe

I was wondering if it's possible for this version of the character to derive from the same place?

Has there been any confirmation given on which universe this version of Commander Landry was from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Commander Landry from Episodes 3 [DIS: Context is for Kings](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5835714/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_i25) and 4 [DIS: The Butcher's Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5870994/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_i25) is from Discovery's Prime Universe. This Landry is killed on-screen by the Tardigrade.

> Mirror/Landry shows up, very much *not dead* in Season 1 Episode 13 ([DIS: What's past is Prologue](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What%27s_Past_Is_Prologue_(episode))).
>  
>  [image: A Mirror universe Commander Landry holds a gun to the head of Mirror Universe Paul Stamets while in the throne room(?) of the ISS Charon.]

Comment: Clearly missed that. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the edits. Mobile answering is clearly not the future.

Comment: @Jontia - Aye. Instead of fixing the site's culture with new policies, SE staff should concentrate on fixing the garbage mobile interface.

Answer (score 4):

So to put a spoiler also:

> As she had no problems with the lights and her counterpart in the mirror universe is seen in the later episodes I would dare say she is from the "prime" universe. Just one ruthless specimen of the human race (and thus a bit unusual for the federation starfleet to let them join them).